# How to get just a certain paragraph using REGEX

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm pretty new to using REGEX and hopefully someone can help me find a solution

I have for example:

---

> text I don't want text I don't want text I don't want text I don't
>   want text I don't want text I don't want text I don't want
>
> ### ***All the colors***
>
> *Bright colors*
>
> - Orange
> - Red
> - Yellow
>
> *Dark Colors*
>
> - Brown
> - Grey
> - Black

[The document ends here i.e. there is no more text under this]

---

I want to use REGEX to ONLY get the following part:

---

> *Bright colors*
>
> - Orange
> - Red
> - Yellow
>
> *Dark Colors*
>
> - Brown
> - Grey
> - Black

[The document ends here i.e. there is no more text under this]

---

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The initial question is misleading in the use of the word "paragraph".  It appears that you are trying to use regex to identify certain words corresponding to light or dark colors.

Comment: Do you want to return *just* the text as output or do you need to return the formatting as well, such as the bullet points?

Comment: I want both the text and the formatting if it's possible

Comment: Please provide the real `html` code you're trying to make this work for. Pretty sure, `beautifulsoup` would be a far better way here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple Regex to catch them all by writing the available colors:

```
(Red|Grey|Yellow|Orange|Brown|Black|Bright Colors|Dark Colors)
```

Test [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8srTGL/2)

If you want to catch everything after `<\h2>` tag, this will do it.

```
\<\/h2\>[\s\S]+
```

Test [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8srTGL/4)

Update:

If you want to catch everything after `Bright colors`, this will do it.

```
Bright Colors[\s\S]+
```

Test [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8srTGL/6)

Comment: That won't work because the words are never the same under the bullet points (e.g. the colors keep changing)

Comment: @Josh I updated my answer and added another code that catches everything after `<h2>` tag

Comment: Thanks so much, but a problem with this is that there are multiple H2 tags in the documents I'm using. The part "Bright colors" is always the same, so I am trying to find a REGEX expression which "Includes Bright Colors", and "Everything under it". I want just this title, and everything under it

Comment: If you want to include the starting formatting of "Bright colors", type it here, and I'll include it

Answer (score 0):

What about the HTML tags that can be embed in the regex input ?

I mean, if the text you want to match is in a special div or between special characteres, your regex would be easier to set. i.e: capture all HTML between ##keep text start## and ##keep text end##

Comment: There is initially a H2 tag, ("All the colors" in my example) and all the text I want is under this H2 tag until the end of the document.